# run chrome WebInspector http HAR with php

Tags: php, google-chrome, curl, web-inspector, har

I make request and save it's HAR from chrome webinspector.
I need run it with php script.
Maybe it can be with curl?

i tried copy as curl from chrome and run as shell_exec and exec, but it not work

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: i need some code to use har

Comment: you just need to find out which cURL options correspond to the HAR options you have